# Feature Engineering in Python with Pandas Using Multiple Rows Per Calculation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, data-science

I have CSV data in the following format:

```
+-----------------+--------+-------------+
| reservation_num |  rate  | guest_name  |
+-----------------+--------+-------------+
| B874576         | 169.95 | Bob Smith   |
| H786234         | 258.95 | Jane Doe    |
| H786234         | 258.95 | John Doe    |
| F987354         | 385.95 | David Jones |
| N097897         | 449.95 | Mark Davis  |
| H567349         | 482.95 | Larry Stein |
| N097897         | 449.95 | Sue Miller  |
+-----------------+--------+-------------+
```

I would like to add a feature (column) to the DataFrame called 'rate_per_person'. It would be calculated by taking the rate for a particular reservation number and dividing it by the total number of guests who have that same reservation number associated with their stay.

Here is my code:

```
#Importing Libraries
import pandas as pd

# Importing the Dataset
ds = pd.read_csv('hotels.csv')

for index, row in ds.iterrows():
    row['rate_per_person'] = row['rate'] / ds[row['reservation_num']].count
```

And the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-3-0668a3165e76>", line 2, in <module>
    row['rate_per_person'] = row['rate'] / ds[row['reservation_num']].count

  File "/Users/<user_name>/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2062, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)

  File "/Users/<user_name>/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2069, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)

  File "/Users/<user_name>/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1534, in _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)

  File "/Users/<user_name>/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 3590, in get
    loc = self.items.get_loc(item)

  File "/Users/<user_name>/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2395, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))

  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 132, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/_libs/index.c:5239)

  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 154, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/_libs/index.c:5085)

  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1207, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/_libs/hashtable.c:20405)

  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1215, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/_libs/hashtable.c:20359)

KeyError: 'B874576'
```

Based on the error message, clearly there is an issue with the `ds[row['reservation_num']].count` portion of the last line of code. However, I am unsure the right way to obtain the number of guests per reservation in a manner that will allow me to programmatically create the new feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 1**
*`pd.Series.value_counts` and `map`*

```
df.rate / df.reservation_num.map(df.reservation_num.value_counts())

0    169.950
1    129.475
2    129.475
3    385.950
4    224.975
5    482.950
6    224.975
dtype: float64
```

---

**Option 2**
*`groupby`, `transform`, and `size`*

```
df.rate / df.groupby('reservation_num').rate.transform('size')

0    169.950
1    129.475
2    129.475
3    385.950
4    224.975
5    482.950
6    224.975
dtype: float64
```

---

**Option 3**
*`np.unique` and `np.bincount`*

```
u, f = np.unique(df.reservation_num.values, return_inverse=True)
df.rate / np.bincount(f)[f]

0    169.950
1    129.475
2    129.475
3    385.950
4    224.975
5    482.950
6    224.975
dtype: float64
```

---

**Option 3.5**
*`np.unique` sorts and therefore doesn't scale as well as `pd.factorize`.  In the context I use them, they do the same thing.  So, I use a function that uses an anecdotal threshold around about the length of array at which one becomes more performant than the other.  It gets numbered as `3.5` because it's by and large the same exact answer as `3`*

```
def factor(a):
    if len(a) > 10000:
        return pd.factorize(a)[0]
    else:
        return np.unique(a, return_inverse=True)[1]

def count(a):
    f = factor(a)
    return np.bincount(f)[f]

df.rate / count(df.reservation_num.values)  

0    169.950
1    129.475
2    129.475
3    385.950
4    224.975
5    482.950
6    224.975
dtype: float64
```

---

**Timing**

```
%timeit df.rate / df.reservation_num.map(df.reservation_num.value_counts())
%timeit df.rate / df.groupby('reservation_num').rate.transform('size')

1000 loops, best of 3: 650 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 768 µs per loop

%%timeit
u, f = np.unique(df.reservation_num.values, return_inverse=True)
df.rate / np.bincount(f)[f]

10000 loops, best of 3: 131 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this operation with `grouppby` and `transform`:

```
df['rate_per_person'] = df.groupby('reservation_num')['rate'].transform(lambda x: x.iloc[0] / x.size)
```

Output:

```
     reservation_num    rate      guest_name  rate_per_person
0   B874576           169.95    Bob Smith             169.950
1   H786234           258.95   Jane Doe               129.475
2   H786234           258.95    John Doe              129.475
3   F987354           385.95     David Jones          385.950
4   N097897           449.95    Mark Davis            224.975
5   H567349           482.95    Larry Stein           482.950
6   N097897           449.95    Sue Miller            224.975
```